# What do you call a person who doesn't feel guilty telling lies

Tags: phrase-requests, pejorative-language, epithet-requests

There are some frequently used quotes people use on Facebook which go like: "Be what you are and you shouldn't change for anybody", "Do not change to impress somebody", etc.

Those quotes sound good, but not from a chronic liar. My question is what do you call a person who doesn't at all feel guilty for his/her lies and instead uses them constantly?

Comment: You might be interested in searching a thesaurus for "charlatan," and picking from among the options, and then if you're not satisfied, providing an example sentence and clarifying the question.

Comment: You might be interested in looking "liar" (so-spelled) up in a dictionary.

Comment: What do your Facebook quotes have to do with the question? They seem completely irrelevant to me…

Answer (score 3):

I would just say Compulsive Liar or Dellusional.

Really having no guilt at all, could even be a Sociopath.

Also could be called a cheat
a
con-artist
a
fabricator or fake
a
maligner or a prevaricator

Comment: I have upvoted this answer, as it provides good suggestions and answers the question, but please consider adding definitions to help improve your answer.

Answer (score 2):

As you mention : *doesn't at all feel guilty for his/her lies and **instead uses them constantly**?*

you might consider the psychological term:

> ***[Pathological lying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pathological_lying)***
>
> Pathological lying (also called pseudologia fantastica and mythomania) is a behavior of habitual or compulsive lying.[1](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/machiavellian) It was first described in the medical literature in 1891 by Anton Delbrueck.[2](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/machiavellian)
>
> **Although it is a controversial topic**,[2](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/machiavellian) pathological lying **has been defined as**
>
> - "falsification entirely disproportionate to any discernible end in view, may be extensive and very complicated, and may manifest over a period of years or even a lifetime".
>
> [1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pathological_lying) The individual may be aware they are lying, or may believe they are telling the truth. Sometimes however, the individual may be lying to make their life seem more exciting when in reality they believe their life is unpleasant or boring.

Note - this answer refers to someone compulsively lieng, and often even lying unconsciously.

It is less appropriate to a cold, premeditated Machiavellian sort of lying

**Machiavellian** or it's synonyms might be other words to describe someone treacherously using lies

> [Mach·i·a·vel·li·an](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/machiavellian)
>   ˌmäkēəˈvelēən,ˌmakēəˈvelēən/
>   adjective
>
> 1.
>   cunning, scheming, and unscrupulous, especially in politics or in advancing one's career.
>
> synonyms:  devious, cunning, crafty, artful, wily, sly, scheming, treacherous, two-faced, Janus-faced, tricky, double-dealing, unscrupulous, deceitful, dishonest; More

Comment: I think that the use of this phrase (pathological liar), apart from its clinical meaning, is understood in everyday conversation to be exactly what the OP is asking for. +1